# i want a hamburger menu to close whenever the user clicks outside,here's my attempt

Tags: javascript, html, menu

/* I've ran into some trouble while trying to make a menu close when a user clicks outside of it, i watched a couple of tutorials but nothing seems to work right now it kinda works but now the actual closing button doesn't work anymore*/

````
    const menuBtn = document.getElementById('hamburger');
    const navToggle = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');
    let x = false;
    let menu = false;
    function menuOpen() {
        if(!x){
            navToggle.classList.toggle('show');
            menuBtn.classList.toggle('open');
            x = true;
            menu = true;
        }else{
            navToggle.classList.remove('show');
            menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
            x = false;
        }
    };
    document.onmouseup = function() {
        if(menu){
            navToggle.classList.remove('show');
            menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
            x = false;
    }
/*here's the html part*/
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
            <title>new project</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Luxurious+Roman&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        </head>
        <body>

            <div onclick="menuOpen()" id="hamburger">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>```
````

Comment: You should use mouseover.

Comment: @AliMustafa it's not working.

Comment: Please have a look at semantic HTML, this menu button should be a `<button type="button">`

Comment: You don't have an element with the id of dropdown-content. Also include your CSS in the code.

Comment: @Andre Nuechter cloned  Ali Mustafa thanks for your help guys i've gotten to work now thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

The key-point is using a global click-handler that checks the click-target and hides the menu when it's appropriate.

Here's an example:.

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
const menu = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

// toggle visibility when the button is clicked
btn.onclick = () => menu.classList.toggle('active');
// hide the menu whenever there's a click not inside the menu or on the button
document.onclick = ({ target }) => {
  if (
    !(target === btn || target === menu || menu.contains(target))
  ) menu.classList.remove('active');
};
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}

ul.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle menu</button>
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Sub</li>
  <li>Sub Two</li>
</ul>
```